# how to create a link button in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

[image]

Here in above figure sleeping like a baby is a `link button`.

I don't want to place a `UITextView` as this simply opens up a `pickerView`

How can I create a `link button` of similar kind in iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UIWebView to display the text. You can supply HTML to link to a URL. Is that what you mean by link button? or what do you want to happen when that text is pressed? You could also subclass the UILabel and detect the touch down event and do something in response to that. Or but that text into a button and make the button look like the surrounding area but act like a button and use one of its control events to respond to the selection.

Answer (score 9):

if "**sleeping like a baby**" is fixed you can have image like that. Put UIButton on that of Custom type. Bind IBAction of Button like

```
-(IBAction)openYourLink
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoururl.com"]];
}
```

Hope it helps.