# Clickable link (Hyperlink)?

Tags: ios, hyperlink

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I cannot find a answer. Is there a way to create a clickable link say in a `MFMailComposeController` or in any other `NSString`? I just want it to be blue and the user will be able to click it and it will go to that link.

Thanks!

Comment: Check these links:

[Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084664/how-to-parse-and-show-hyperlinks-phone-number-email-addresses-etc-in-uilabel)

[Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839637/how-to-create-a-link-button-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the mail msg body try this - `[mailComposer setMessageBody:msg isHTML:YES];`. So when you put the message compose it of HTML & put this setting so that the mail is sent as HTML...

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer; 
mailComposer  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[mailComposer setSubject:@"Mail subject"];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:msg isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
[mailComposer release];
return;
```

Comment: what if you're using UIActivityViewController and don't have ability to set html to yes?